# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. >Finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android

I have been facing this error for more than 2 days now
Can any tell whats wrong with this code

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1**

**Here what I have tried (one by one) based on other stackoverflow submissions**

1. Added dexOptions
2. multiDexEnabled = true
3. Clean Project
4. Changed SDK 1.7.0_25 to 1.7.0_79 
5. Changed gradle build to 1.3.0 to 1.5.0

My app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.foodyroute.food"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.01"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),       'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res/anim']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src/main/rs', 'src/main/rs/']
    }
  }
}
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'



}
```

Here is Project Build Gradle

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
       jcenter()
  }
}
```

Here what the console says

```
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE`
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE    
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72420Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2420Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2420Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps810Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:dexDebug
 UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:         Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatBase$UnreadConversation;
    at        com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:         Landroid/support/v4/hardware/display/DisplayManagerCompat$LegacyImpl;
at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:122)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:161)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:732)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at     com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at     com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
2 errors; aborting
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program     Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: You have some library duplication: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: ...`. Some of your support libraries are trying to add the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Your support libraries are in conflict. Your CardView is at 23.2, and your RecyclerView is always at the latest version, which is 24.2.x right now.

Try to make your support libraries version match.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'
```

Easiest way to do that,

(note: I'm not sure of the availability of these libraries for version 22.2.1, specifically)

```
ext {
    // Variables to keep libraries consistent
    supportLibrary = "22.2.1"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibrary}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibrary}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibrary}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibrary}"
}
```

---

You may also want to update your Gradle plugin to the latest version

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
```

And in `gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties`, make sure you have 2.14.1

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip
```